# whilelopp not properly while fetching two table values

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have two table,i want fetch two table values,this code should working fine but count=2 means loop running 2 times,return the output of 2 times,like count=3 means loop running in 3 times return output 3 times,what i did mistake....

---

*OUTPUT*

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "count":2,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "t_id":"STV1",
         "t_title":"Horoscope Uploading",
         "t_project":"1",
         "t_sub_project":"Sub-project",
         "t_desc":"cfdgdgdcf",
         "t_priority":"Urgent",
         "t_assign_to":"AE098",
         "t_assign_on":"2016-04-13 12:03:49",
         "t_started_on":"2016-04-14 05:30 PM",
         "t_due_on":"2016-04-22 05:30 PM",
         "t_complete_percentage":"100",
         "t_est_hours":"35",
         "t_worked":"10 Hours",
         "t_comment":"dfhfghfgfsfhfgh",
         "t_created_on":"2016-04-13 12:03:49",
         "t_edited_on":"2016-04-14 07:01:06",
         "t_status":"3",
         "t_delete_on":"0"
      }
   ]
}{  
   "status":"success",
   "count":2,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "t_id":"STV1",
         "t_title":"Horoscope Uploading",
         "t_project":"1",
         "t_sub_project":"Sub-project",
         "t_desc":"cfdgdgdcf",
         "t_priority":"Urgent",
         "t_assign_to":"AE098",
         "t_assign_on":"2016-04-13 12:03:49",
         "t_started_on":"2016-04-14 05:30 PM",
         "t_due_on":"2016-04-22 05:30 PM",
         "t_complete_percentage":"100",
         "t_est_hours":"35",
         "t_worked":"10 Hours",
         "t_comment":"dfhfghfgfsfhfgh",
         "t_created_on":"2016-04-13 12:03:49",
         "t_edited_on":"2016-04-14 07:01:06",
         "t_status":"3",
         "t_delete_on":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Same ans but i will come two times,how to fix this problem**

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include('dbconfig.php');
 if(empty($_SESSION['email'])){
   header('Location:login.php');
 }
 $dapartment = $_POST['department'];
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_employee WHERE emp_designation='$dapartment'");
 $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
 $return = array();
 while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $emp_id=$r['emp_id'];
  if($count > 0){
  $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE t_assign_to='$emp_id'");
   while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)){
    $data[] = $row;
   }
   $return=array('status'=>'success','count'=>$count,'data'=>$data);
   echo json_encode($return);
  }else{
    $return=array('status'=>'not found','count'=>$count,'data'=>$data);
    echo json_encode($return);
  }
 } 
?>
```

Comment: What problem you are exactly facing ?

Comment: Why are you not using a joined query here instead of nested loops?

Comment: @TirthPatel You're wrong! There is php5-mysqlnd extension to keep support of old code. Must agree that this kinds of code in most apps are more than PDO.

Comment: @Wobbles tell this solution ,how to write joined query.

Comment: See in `task` table, where `id`=>1 data is present 2 times ?

Comment: @yuvi This will teach you about SQL joins http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp, Looks like you need to join on `emp_id` and `t_assign_to`

Answer (score 1):

As @Wobbles mentioned. You can use joins.

```
session_start();
include('dbconfig.php');
if(empty($_SESSION['email'])){
  header('Location:login.php');
}

$dapartment = $_POST['department'];

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_employee te, task t WHERE te.emp_designation='$dapartment' AND te.emp_id = t.t_assign_to");
$data = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $data[] = $r;
}   

$return = array(
  'status' => ((empty($data))?'not found':'success'), 
  'count' => sizeof($data), 
  'data' => $data
);

header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
echo json_encode($return);
```

For more info, please have a look on [mysql-using-joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: this will not work, cuz @yuvi has data structure one-to-many. join will help in situation one-to-one.

Comment: I know, but in this answer You'll get a huge data response with all data in one row. It's not optimal. In most frameworks there is eager-loading principle when Model gets related things.

Comment: Because, there are more than 1 data present in your DB Table with same ID @yuvi'

Answer (score 0):

1) You've to collect `emp_ids` using first query

2) Then get all tasks by doing `WHERE IN ()`

3) Collect all tasks to array

4) You may output `json_encode` once, otherwise You json is invalid

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbconfig.php');
if(empty($_SESSION['email'])){
    header('Location:login.php');
}

header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');


$dapartment = $_POST['department'];

$q = "SELECT * FROM task_employee WHERE emp_designation='".mysql_real_escape_string($dapartment)."'";
$q = mysql_query($q);
$taskEmployees = array(); 
while($taskEmployee = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $taskEmployees[$taskEmployee['emp_id']] = $taskEmployee;
}
$empIds = array_keys($taskEmployees);

$tasks = array();

if(!empty($empIds)) {
  // this query tells mysql to return tasks of assigned users 
  $q = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE t_assign_to IN (".implode(',', $empIds).")";
  $q = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

  //  generating array of tasks associated by emp_id (t_assign_to field)
  while($task = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
      $tasks[] = array(
        'task' => $task,
        'task_employee' => $taskEmployees[$task['t_assign_to']]
      );
  }
}

echo json_encode(array(
    'status'    => (empty($empIds))? 'not found' : 'success',
    'count'     => sizeof($tasks),
    'data'      => $tasks
));
```

In JS You'll use them like (it's for not to merge field names):

```
for(var r in records) {
  var record = records[r];
  console.log(record.task, record.taks_employee);
}
```

Comment: Getting error like this <b>Warning</b>: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/srisanka/public_html/cupid/TV/php/department-check.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br/>
{"status":"success","count":0,"data":[]}

Comment: just copy and paste your code but still i am getting same error

Comment: Unknown column'AE098'in'where clause'

Comment: AE098 is emp_id or t_assign_to

Comment: You've not tell anybody that You've emp_id of varchar type. Now it's fixed.

Comment: Now got it but,only task table value it will return,how to return the task_employee table values

Comment: understood what You need :)  checkout new answer

Comment: @ num8er  ,still i am not getting task_employee table values ,where you return in task_employee???

Answer (score 0):

Just use an inner join so you dont have to iterate employee id's

```
SELECT *
FROM task_employee
INNER JOIN task
ON task_employee.emp_id=task.t_assign_to
ORDER BY task_employee.emp_id;
```

Comment: My task table totally 3 rows are there your so your code it will be return 3 times

Comment: @yuvi It will return 3 rows once.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use a join. You can select from two tables in one query.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('dbconfig.php');

    if(empty($_SESSION['email'])){
      header('Location:login.php');
    }

    $dapartment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['department']);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_employee, task WHERE task_employee.emp_designation='$dapartment' AND task_employee.t_assign_to = task.emp_id");
    if(false == $sql){
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
     $data = [];
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
          $data[] = $row;
     }

     if (count($data) <= 0){
          $return = array('status'=>'not found','count'=>$count,'data'=>$data);
     }
     else{
          $return = array('status'=>'success','count'=>$count,'data'=>$data);
     }
     echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: <br/>
<b>Warning</b>: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/srisanka/public_html/cupid/TV/php/department-check.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br/>
<br/>
<b>Warning</b>: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/srisanka/public_html/cupid/TV/php/department-check.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br/>
{"status":"not found","count":null,"data":[]}

Comment: You can use mysql_error() to find the error. I updated my answer with error checking so you can find the issue.